# terrafrom aws_secretsmanager_secret_version force to recate

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to add a secret string to a secret manager.

I want to force so the secret_string that I'm doing at the terraform apply will force to change the values that exist in the secret right now (if changed manually)
there is a way to force this resource to be applied to be like in the terraform file even if there is no change on the secret_string value?
those are the resource I'm using:

```
locals {
    env = {
    key = value
  }
}
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "sversion" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secretsmanager.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(local.env)
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: "if there is no change on the secret_string" why would you for change? What change, if there is literally no change to be made?

Comment: If I'm changing the secret value from the AWS console (putting value2 for key) and then running 'terraform apply' it doesn't change.
so I want to ability to change from the console but if there is a apply so whats in the code will be selected @Marcin

Comment: This is bad practice. All your changes should be done in TF, not AWS console. That's the entire point of using TF in the first place.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes we want to change the value for testing (without waiting for a new deployment ). and I want to make sure that what in the TF will be selected in case of new apply